# Store image into database or in application folder?

Tags: android

Hi i want to store an image in my android application.I am confused that should i store it in the database or in an application folder?which is a better option and y??

Comment: you image will remain static ? i mean you will not download images to your application ?

Comment: no.images will not be downloaded..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends from the type of image you will want to store. It's confidentially? Or public?

Create a database only for saving an image it would be non-optimal, but it you have a database created, for example to save user profiles (name, surname, birthday, etc), it could be a great option to save a profile image in the database.

Anyway, i think sdcard is the best option. And create a custom folder for your application and save all the images there ;)

Hope this helps...

Comment: So you have a database created in your application? If you want to have centralized all the information in the database this is the best option. The database is only local?

Comment: The images of the users profiles are private? If they are not very big images,  you can store it in the database. If we are talking of bigger images, it could not be a good option because it will make your database size bigger and it will slow down

Comment: According to this, I will probably save them in the database, because if you want to export later the database, you will have all the information centralized.

Answer (score 2):

Store it on the SDCard if possible else use application folder.

Comment: cause application folder uses phone memory that's y ur suggesting SD card??

Comment: ca you plz have a look at oriolpons ans what do u think?

Answer (score 1):

Its depends on the size of images, you want to provide security to that images etc..

If not bother then store images in a application folder `/asset` , `/drawable` or `external storage` (If use external storage then save path of those images in database) and use it directly, To store in database is quite some ugly way, convert it into blob type and then store, re fetching from database convert into byte to bitmap..